# dealloc and release issue

Tags: objective-c

i know this issue was discussed many times before , but i have a simple question.
after reading all the apple's rules to manage the memory, i know this :

if i allocate an object , i own it and have to release it . so i have to do :

```
ran *me = [[ran alloc] init];
//do somthing
[me release];
```

so now , the retain count is 0, after i release ran object.

BUT i was also read that when retain count of an object is 0, the dealloc method is being invoked .

so my question is, after i took down the retain count to 0, DO i have to release again the object at the dealloc?

```
-(void)dealloc
[me release];
```

or that the first release did the job ?
otherwise, why dealloc is being called anyway ? if the retain count=0 we are ok no ??

thanks a lot .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need to release again in there - in fact, don't do it!

The reason dealloc is being called is so that clean-up may occur.  For example, if you allocated memory in your class, you can free it up there.  And remember that the retain count could reach 2, 3, 4, 5.... so just because a `release` is done, you don't (as an outside user of the class) know that the dealloc should be called.  That's how it is different than a release.

One thing to note is that the dealloc method may not be immediately run when the count hits 0.  It could be done much later.

Comment: why retain count could be 2,3,4 ? every time i alloc it, i release it, so it should never be more that one unless after alloctaion, i have another one, so its 2, and then dealloc is called? and if so, after what number of retain exactly dealloc is called? isnt it exact sciense ? cant i know exactly when ? so if every allocation is release at some point, am i ok for sure ?

Comment: @Rant - perhaps in this situation you only have 1.. but in general in the programming language, you could of course [object retain]; to increase the count to 2, 3, ..   When you reach a count of 0, no matter how you got there, dealloc is called.  But not immediately - it happens at the leisure of the runtime.  The point is that yes, the count must become 0 eventually to free the memory, and when that happens dealloc is called.

Comment: thanks but if the count is 0, so the system memory is ok, so why the dealloc is being called? 0 means - no memory leaks ?  apple docs just not clear about that .

Comment: does someone can explain that ? how is it that somehow developers just dont understand this issue too well ???

Answer (score 1):

Depends if the variable "me" is an instance variable, or "ivar" as it's called.

For ivars, you put the release in the dealloc. For everything else, you must release it in the same method you create it.

Unless of course it's an autoreleased object, but that's a different story...

Comment: what you say here is strange. according to apple , every alloc should be released in that method, right after you finish with your object . they never mention ivars(you means property-retain ? ) so if i release it after alloc it, why dealloc is being called ?

Answer (score 0):

First i think you mean  [me release];

Second you only must release it in dealloc if you retained it in the .h file like
@property (nonatomic, retain) ran *me;

With this you set the retaincout of *me to 1 then alloc init it to 2 in .m file, then you have to release *me two times. First time for the alloc init, second time in dealloc for the retain in .h

Hope this helps.

Comment: what ??? i cant understand what you just said..its complitly different from the apple documantaions . check my question,and your answer. i didnt talk about retain, but about a class that alloc another class during the m file  . this SHOULD be released not in dealloc, but after alloc.

Comment: Yes, this SHOULD be released not in dealloc, but after alloc and i explained why. If you not use the @property retain, you not use the -(void)dealloc. So i thought it was the anwser to your question. :)